# How to Use Module Controllers in Kohana 3?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, controller, kohana-3

For the following application directory structure under / in Kohana 3:

- application

  - classes
  - controller

    - controller1.php
- modules

  - admin
  - classes

    - controller
    - controller2.php

And the urls be: /controller1 and /admin/controller2?

I seem to be missing something though because I keep getting a 404 error with the /admin/controller. What am I doing incorrectly?

The exact error is:

> HTTP_Exception_404 [ 404 ]: The requested URL admin/borrowers was not found on this server.

And I don't have any custom routes setup. This is a very vanilla K3 install at this point.

Comment: Could you give some more information? What precise error do you get? Can you give information about your routes?

Comment: @ikke - Do I need to add the admin module to the routes for the site?

Comment: No. You have to be aware that you can only use one class with the same name in one project. The ones in your application folder would be picked first, and the others are ignored. Check [this](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/files) guide page.

Comment: @ikke - Please note the updated example. You are correct of course, but the controller I'm trying to load from the module doesn't have a corresponding mate under the application directory so my example was incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory structure seems to be a little of.

Using a module doesn't automatically means you have a subdirectory. The default route defines the following url structure:

```
/[controller]/[action]
```

So for the directory structure that you have given, you get the following:

```
/controller2/
```

The action can be left out, but it will default to `index`.

If you want a special admin subdirectory, you would first have to create that subdirectory in you modules classes directory like this:

```
/admin/classes/admin/controller2.php
```

Then you would have to add another route that handles the subdirectory. You can find more information about that in the [userguide](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/routing#uri)