# How to use controllers from modules in Kohana 3.2

Tags: routes, kohana

I readed the [userguide](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/routing#uri) also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444286/how-to-use-module-controllers-in-kohana-3), but still have problem with the following in Kohana 3.2.

I have a controller at the location:
project-dir > modules > module_name > classes > controllers > test.php.

How to call this controller from url? Need I to set up a route for this? If yes, how?
How you resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a no-problem; if you have the default route, you will access that controller the same way you access application controllers. The problem I see here is in your directory naming, using controller*s* instead of controller (not reflecting the actual class name).

I'd suggest you read more about the [Cascading File System](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/files)

Comment: Why are we people trying to make simple things complicated :| :) Thanks for help!